# Find record by index in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

So in the same way that you could do `@items.active.first` to get the first item, is there a way to select something else, like 56th?

Obviously `@items.active.fiftysixth` doesn't work, but is there some other method for accessing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the collection is a relation, you can use offset (.first just translates to `limit 1` in SQL)

```
@items.active.offset(55).first
```

Or, if it's an array:

```
@items.active[55]
```

Comment: The 56th element is index 55. Ruby arrays start at 0.

Comment: `@items.active.offset(55).first`. While `@items.active[55]` is very bad idea

Comment: @fl00r it depends. If he only ever wants the 56th entry, then offset is preferred, if he wants many entries, or to traverse the collection based on some calculation he's probably better fetching the whole collection and indexing it as an array.

Comment: As an aside, do you think rails guarantees row order in a given table?

Comment: @PerryHorwich I believe Rails simply puts them in whatever order the database returns them. If you specify an `.order`, then they'll be in that order. Otherwise, there are no guarantees.

Comment: Thx MrTheWalrus.  So then, using something like @items.active.offset(55).first to navigate up and down a table may yield different results than loading the same table into an array and navigating the array up and down.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PerryHorwich That's correct. In practice, it probably won't happen that often, but if you're going to be doing something like that, you should specify the same .order each time to avoid getting bitten by it.